# OKI 10EX driver for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have an old OKIpage 10EX which worked perfect until I Installed Windows 7 Ultimate.

Does anyone know where I can find a driver for my OKI 10EX printer?

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit? Have you already tried the original drivers?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://compudirect.net/vista.php) is a link to get the latest OKI drivers. Find your model and click the download button to open a new window where you select your model from a drop-down. It does not look like the drivers for the OKIPAGE10ex have been updated in a *long* time. If you're running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

In the Add Printer wizard's "Install the printer driver" page, click the "Windows Update" button. After the update completes, you will see your printer's model under "Okidata."

See http://my.okidata.com/dsdownWeb.nsf/driverlookup/5906E9513F840DF38525779800741840?OpenDocument.